# Distance between two canvas co-ordinates in javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm well acquainted with basic math and know the equations, but when I try to implement them in canvas they fail.

Here's the relevant code:

```
    function distance(one,two){
    var a, b
    if(one[0] > one[1]){
        a = one[1] - one[0]
    }else{
        a = one[0] - one[1]
    }
    if(two[0] > two[1]){
        b = two[1] - two[0]
    }else{
        b = two[0] - two[1]
    }

    var c = a^2 + b^2;
    return Math.sqrt(c);
}

radius = distance([centerX,e.clientX], [centerY,e.clientY])
context.fillCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, "white");
```

[Here's the code in action](http://fridgecow.uk.to/gallifreyan)

As you can see, the circle is far too short and I don't know why... when I remove the sqrt, it becomes out of whack very quickly.

Comment: (a - b)*(a - b) === (b - a) * (b - a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` does not do what you think it does.

```
js> 8^2
10
js> Math.pow(8,2)
64
```

Comment: It's performing bitwise XOR. And Python uses `**`.

Comment: How to do powers must have completely escaped me then... thanks anyway, code works perfectly now (although I'm using a*a because Math.pow is longer)